# Using function keys without [FN] key with Apple Wireless Keyboard on Windows 7 Machine (no bootcamp)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, windows-registry, function-keys

I currently use the Apple Wireless Keyboard on my work PC (just my preference).

For the most part it works fine. Since I do a lot of programming, I end up using the function keys a lot. However, in order to use the function keys I have to press the `[FN]` key as well. This makes key combinations like `[CTRL]` + `[SHIFT]` + `[F8]` a handful.

Is there anyway to change my settings (for example changing a registry value) so that I don't have to press the `[FN]` when using my function keys?

**Caveat**
I'm using a foreign language variant of the keyboard, so programs like the [Apple Wireless Keyboard Helper](http://uxsoft.cz/projects/apple-wireless-keyboard/) won't work.